# Calculating Weighted Average in Reporting Services 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to calculate average weighted value for each group item in my report. I used all of the suggestions at [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/cef96df9-17b5-450b-a112-989fe7fd5004), but all of them give me the following error:

> Warning   1   [rsAggregateOfMixedDataTypes] The Value expression for the
>   textrun ‘textbox134.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses an aggregate
>   function on data of varying data types.  Aggregate functions other
>   than First, Last, Previous, Count, and CountDistinct can only
>   aggregate data of a single data type.

Any suggestion for the best way to calculate weighted average. My latest attempt is this:

```
=iif(sum(iif(Fields!weight.Value is nothing,0,Fields!weight.Value))= 0, 0, sum(iif((Fields!myData.Value * Fields!weight.Value) is nothing,0,(Fields!myData.Value * Fields!weight.Value)))/ sum(Fields!weight.Value))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the exeption description , I suspect that your field isn't set with any dataset and therefor you can calculate aggregate functions , if you using a single text box - try to use a table (use single column and delete the rows so aventually you will have a Header cell), and make sure in the table properties that you linked the right dataset to it.

About your expression, try this one insted:

`=iif(sum(iif(IsNothing(Fields!weight.Value),0,Fields!weight.Value))= 0, 0, sum(iif(IsNothing(Fields!myData.Value * Fields!weight.Value),0,(Fields!myData.Value * Fields!weight.Value)))/ sum(Fields!weight.Value))`